# Contigency table

Tags: java

I am struggling to find the Java code for this problem. Firstly, I am in a beginner level and this question were hard for me to answer. I know that this used a 2D array right? But I having problem to write the Java code for this question.

Here is the question:

> Write a Java program that
>
> 1. queries a user for the number of rows and columns of a contingency table,
> 2. read the data, row by row and
> 3. displays the data in tabular form along with the row totals, column totals and grand
>      total.
>
> For example if the six data of 2x3 table are
>
> 1,3,6,7,9, and 8.  the program displays these six numbers together
>   with the appropriate totals as
>
> ```
> 1 3 6   | 10  
> 7 9 8   | 24  
> 8 12 14 | 34
> ```
>
> The character '|' is used to separate the data from the row totals

Comment: Homework?  If yes, tag it as such.  You'll also do better if you post some code that demonstrates your mastery of 2D arrays.  This question, as written, is little more than a "haz the codes" request.

Comment: owh, i'm sorry..this was my assgnment for java programming. i just guessing that it is use the 2D array.

Comment: Yes, look at what I gave you.  It does use a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by recommending that you forget about "array" and think more about "class".  Java's an object-oriented language.  Encapsulate the behavior you want in a class.  Let's call it `Tableau`.

You have at least four different behaviors that your class needs to get right:

1. Reading values into a Tableau from a Stream or Reader of some kind (e.g. `PrintStream`, `FileInputStream`)
2. Calculating the row and column sums for the Tableau
3. Rendering the Tableau as a String.
4. Writing a Tableau to an OutputStream or Writer of some kind.

Computer science is about breaking complex tasks into smaller, more manageable pieces.  It's called "decomposition".  Here's a good opportunity to learn it.

So here's a start:

```
package model;

public class Tableau {
    private int numRows; 
    private int numCols; 
    private int[][] values;

    public Tableau(int numRows, int numCols) {
        if (numRows <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("numRows must be positive");
        if (numCols <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("numCols must be positive");
        this.numRows = numRows; 
        this.numCols = numCols; 
        this.values = new int[numRows+1][numCols+1];
    }

    // You add the rest
    public String toString() { 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code. But i still don't know what should i do with "you add the rest" space at the code above. should i continue with "public static void main" things? coz when i enter this code to netbeans and it shows "Tableau does not have main method".

Comment: Yes, add the main method and everything else that's needed to implement this class fully.  I *deliberately* did not give you the whole thing.  You may have to fire up one or two brain cells to finish this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your example:
First create a 2x3 array,
Then ask the user for the inputs of each cell (hint: two for loops)
Then, as you print the rows, go over the rows and add them up to print he last number.
At the end go over the columns and add them. Hen print.

Actual code will be doing the homework for you, but if you can translate these steps into java you hold be fine and would gt a good understanding of 2D arrays.

Best.